# Is it possible to determine who owns a segment of dynamic memory during runtime?

Tags: c, memory-management

Suppose I allocate a piece of dynamic memory, and it was successful. Later on, there is a possibility that this piece of memory no longer belongs to the user. Is it possible to determine if the user still owns this piece of dynamic memory? i.e.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
   int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));

   /* ... ptr may have been freed ... */

   belongToUser(ptr); /* <- some sort of check? */
}
```

Comment: If you want to know whether the pointer has been freed at some point, simply set it to `NULL` after you free it. Later on if it is `NULL` you know it has been freed.

Comment: Short answer: no, you can't to this. You need to track the memory you have allocated. Once a pointer allocated via `malloc` has been freed, it's gone forever.

Comment: Unless you `free` it, the object belongs to the process. What do you mean?

Comment: So it seems to be that nulling the pointer is the only way? If the piece of memory was freed, is there more than one method of determining the memory no longer usable?

Comment: There are methods, see my answer, but don't use them please

Comment: @Miket25 It's a reasonable question (I'm not sure why it's been downvoted), but yes, the answer is: there are simply not any standard functions to help you manage your malloced memory.  *You* must remember whether a pointer is valid/invalid, whither it has been malloced/freed.  Typically this is done by setting invalid pointers to NULL.  But there are no standard functions to say whether an arbitrary pointer is valid versus invalid, malloced versus free, or anything like that.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks! Nulling the freed pointer sounds to be the consensus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a (neither clean nor safe) possibility to check:

1. Register a signal handler for SIGSEGV
2. Access the memory
3. Return not mapped if the signal handler was run, mapped otherwise

As mentioned, I'd never recommend to check, but to write C programs that remember (`pointer = NULL`).

Comment: Slightly off-topic answer since there was no platform mentioned, signals and handlers might not exist at all

Comment: You're right, thats only one disadvantage of this method. But, afaik, it is the only one.

Comment: That's a very neat answer @xanoetux!

Comment: This is a poor, if not wrong, solution, because accessing memory that has been freed does not necessarily signal. Accessing freed memory yields in "undefined behaviour" (google that).

Comment: @MichaelWalz noted

Comment: Demonstration: http://ideone.com/rMLbww the output of this program is undefined. Actually it prints "0" and does not segfault. So this solution won't work in this environnment. I'm tempted to downvote.

Comment: Although not recommended, the (freed!) memory is usable then. You don't know for what time, of course.

Comment: It's not only "not recommended", but using freed memory yields in UB (undefined behaviour) and therefore it's always wrong.